# Spring security only returns root of controller

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

After adding spring security to my application it only seems to return the root of my controller.

When I put a URL in that should return json in the "working" version it returns json as expected.  In the version I have that uses spring security it only returns the root of my controller.

Below is my tomcat output.

```
DEBUG - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/service/products/2'; to: '/service/products/2'
DEBUG - Candidate is: '/service/products/2'; pattern is /**; matched=true
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG - Requested session ID8FA5D77A75BFF4D7EBDD063710EFF5F4 is invalid.
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG - /service/products/2 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/service/products/2'; to: '/service/products/2'
DEBUG - Candidate is: '/service/products/2'; pattern is /service/products/removeproduct**; matched=false
DEBUG - Public object - authentication not attempted
DEBUG - /service/products/2 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG - DispatcherServlet with name 'cr' processing GET request for [/service/products/2]
DEBUG - Matching patterns for request [/service/products/2] are [/service/products/{productId}]
DEBUG - URI Template variables for request [/service/products/2] are {productId=2}
DEBUG - Mapping [/service/products/2] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [com.cr.controllers.ProductsController@60326032] and 3 interceptors
DEBUG - Last-Modified value for [/service/products/2] is: -1
DEBUG - Invoking request handler method: public void com.cr.controllers.ProductsController.get(javax.servlet.ServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
DEBUG - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'cr': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG - Successfully completed request
DEBUG - Chain processed normally
DEBUG - SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
DEBUG - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I added the following to my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
        classpath:spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" path-type="ant">
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/products/removeProduct**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I also moved down to version 3.0.5 for spring. here is are the spring dependencies in my pom.xml. The working version is on 3.2.0 / 3.1.3

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was an issue with the spring version combinations I was using.  I made the following changes to my Pom and one change to the spring-security.xml and it resolved the issue.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring security xml update

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't match the version numbers in your spring namespaces (XML) to the version of spring that you have in your POM file?

Comment: I updated the namespaces, however for my future reference, what would be the adverse effects of not having the right namespace?

Comment: Ideally it will not cause any problems.  I have has projects go into production with non-matching versions here with no known  issues.  However I have also, in the past, had an application that would not even start do to this exact issue.  So now it is one thing that I look at when diagnosing a Spring application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are including Spring 3.2 in your POM file (specifically, 3.2.0.RELEASE), then your config file should start with:

```
<beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"
>
```

Note that the version numbers on the schema locations match the version number (major/minor) of the Spring Framework that you are using.

[I tried to add this as a comment to your answer, zmanc, but the URL-like strings were reinterpreted by the system and converted to links (minus the protocols, and with the longer ones being truncated).]